# VBA errors when you specify .Interior.ColorIndex in user function

Tags: excel, vba

I try to write procedures for Excel 2010 in VBA but the error constantly flies

```
Public Sub SetClrIndex (rng as Range, ColorIndex as Integer)
    rng.Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex 'here "Error 1004: application or object error"
End Sub
```

if before `rng.Cells(1,1).Interior` put `Set` then error "Error 424: object required"

the range specified by the user is transferred to the procedure

Tell me how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `.Interior.ColorIndex` problem but the `rng` problem: it is not set (it does not refer to anything), it's just dimensioned as an object of "Range" type. Make sure you are *passing* an already assigned range to this sub.

The way to test for this and avoid the error popping up:

```
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
    End If
```

EDIT:
@woojin provided additional info: *"this procedure is called from a user-defined function..."* This explains it (credit to @Rory): *"You cannot change a cell's colour from a UDF, even indirectly."*

Comment: did such a check - the range exists

Answer (score 0):

You should also supply the code that calls your function so that those who want to help have a full picture. Since you didn't supply that, I made code up and this seems to work fine. Perhaps you can sort out your problem starting from this working code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Application.InputBox("select range", , , Type:=8)
MsgBox "the current ColorIndex is " & r.Interior.ColorIndex
SetClrIndex r, 0
End Sub


Public Sub SetClrIndex(rng As Range, ColorIndex As Integer)
    rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex 'works fine
End Sub
```

Comment: this procedure is called from a user-defined function that returns an integer if some cell is full (CRLF - is next string) `Public Function IsValue(cell as Range) as Integer 'CRLF' If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then 'CRLF' SetClrIndex cell, xlColorIndexAutomatic 'CRLF' IsValue=1 'CRLF' End If 'CRLF' End Function`

Comment: You cannot change a cell's colour from a UDF, even indirectly.